# Python input() not being called during function call

Tags: python, function, recursion, input

This is a code snippet from a simple text based game I'm writing to improve my Python skills.
I plan on using `input_check()` to simplify a lot of code that I'll write later on in the project, but I can't get it to work at the moment. I'm running this on the latest master of VS Code with the Pylance extension, which doesn't flag any errors in my code. I've run multiple tests to make sure `input_check()` is the issue, and removing it and simply running the code multiple times works just fine.

```
import time

def rules():
  print("The rules of this game are:")
  time.sleep(0.5)
  print("rules")
  time.sleep(0.5)
  print("rules")
  time.sleep(0.5)
  print("rules")
  time.sleep(0.5)
  print("rules")
  time.sleep(0.5)
  print("rules")
  time.sleep(0.5)
  input_check("Do you understand?\n", rules(), "Ok. Starting game...")
  
def input_check(question: str, function, confirmation: str):  
  yes_no = input(question)

  if yes_no.lower() == "n" or "no":
    function
  elif yes_no.lower() == "y" or "yes":
    print(confirmation)
    time.sleep(1)
  else:
    print("Invalid input.")
    input_check(question, function, confirmation)


input_check("Do you know the rules?\n", rules(), "Ok. Starting game...")
```

I'm almost a complete newbie to Python so I have no idea if taking the `function` argument and then running it as a function later in `input_check()` would work or not, but that's not the issue.

There should be a prompt run to define `yes_no` with `input()` but it never reaches this. Instead, it seems like it skips ahead to running `rules()` (which should only happen if the user inputs 'no' or 'n'), and `rules()` runs continuously until stopped, completely skipping `input_check()` .

My questions are:

1. Why is `input_check()` being completely ignored?
2. Can you run code taken as a parameter as-is (the `function` parameter) or is there an extra step I need to make it run?
3. Is there a better/more efficient way to do this? (e.g. a package that parses input that avoids having to make your own function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this statement:

```
input_check("Do you know the rules?\n", rules(), "Ok. Starting game...")
```

When you do that, Python is going to CALL the `rules` function immediately, so it can pass it's result to `input_check`.  Your `rules` function prints out a bunch of stuff, then has the exact same line, which is going to call `rules()` again, and again, and again, and again...  It never gets a chance to call `input_check`.  It's still processing the parameters.

If you want to PASS the function object but not call it, don't use the parens:

```
input_check("Do you know the rules?\n", rules, "Ok. Starting game...")
```

Note that the `input_check` function will keep calling the passed in function.  You DON'T need to call it again inside `rules`.

### Followup

This does not do what you think:

```
  if yes_no.lower() == "n" or "no":
```

That's parsed as:

```
  if (yes_no.lower() == "n")   or "no":
```

and since "no" is true, that if will always be taken.  You should use one of these:

```
  if yes_no.lower() in ("n" or "no"):
  if yes_no.lower()[0] == "n":
```

Next, you have this:

```
  if yes_no.lower() == "n" or "no":
    function
```

Here, you DO want to call the function, so you need to add the parens:

```
  if yes_no.lower()[0] == "n":
    function()
```

Comment: This worked amazingly, almost! That problem is solved, but now no matter what `yes_no` is input as `rules()` is called. It shouldn't be running rules() at all if the user answers yes or y.

Answer (score 0):

```
inputCheck("Do you know the rules?\n", rules(), "Ok. Starting game...")
```

You don't need any parantheses() after rules, instead of passing function as an argument you're running it. Write it like this:-

```
inputCheck("Do you know the rules?\n", rules, "Ok. Starting game...")
```

Also here:-

```
if yes_no.lower() == "n" or "no":
   function
```

You need to add () after function, write:-

```
if yes_no.lower() == "n" or "no":
  function()
```

Let me know if it does solve problem

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem is you used `rules()` like a parameter to pass a function. You need to change to: `inputCheck("Do you know the rules?\n", rules, "Ok. Starting game...")`.

rules(): will calling function rules()

rules: functions can be passed as a parameter to another function.

You can come here to get more information:

[What is the difference between calling function with parentheses and without in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001292/what-is-the-difference-between-calling-function-with-parentheses-and-without-in).

**Note**: I saw your sample code has many errors (when using `def rules()` like an object or function). You should to learn how to debug, it will help you fix errors effective

Answer (score 0):

along with the other answers, I found another semantic error: your first if statement will always evaluate to true, as it will be evaluating the boolean value of 'no' as follows

```
if yes_no.lower() == 'n' or 'no' == True:
```

since a non empty string evaluates to true, this statement will always execute. instead of what you have, you can add

```
yes_no.lower() == 'no'
```

giving you

```
if yes_no.lower() == "n" or yes_no.lower() == "no":
```

making it so that statement evaluates as true only if yes_no.lower is 'n' or 'no'

for further clarification, see

[Why is my python if statement not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790669/why-is-my-python-if-statement-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a lot of explanation for the code's current behavior but not
much practical advice on how to do what I think you're trying to do. You don't
need to pass the rules function back and forth. You need the most important
tool for getting user input: a while-true loop.

```
def game():
    if not yesno('Do you know the rules'):
        rules()
    print("Ok. Starting game ...")

def rules():
    while True:
        print("The rules of this game are ... BLAH BLAH")
        if yesno('Do you understand'):
            break

def yesno(question):  
    while True:
        yn = input(f'{question}? [yes/no]: ').lower()
        if yn in ('y', 'yes'):
            return True
        elif yn in ('n', 'no'):
            return False
        else:
            print("Invalid input.")
```